# Fourier sine series pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Consider the step function $f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & -\pi < x < 0 \\ 1 & 0 \leq x < \pi \end{cases}$

1. Calculate the coefficients $a_n$ of the sin series $f(x) =
       \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin nx$.
2. What is the pointwise limit of this series, for each $x \in
       (-\pi,\pi)$?
3. Does this series converge uniformly? Prove that it does or does not.

---

I've managed to do the first part, $$a_n = \frac{2(1-(-1)^{n})}{\pi n}.$$ But I am getting confused with all the information available on the web regarding pointwise and uniform convergence of Fourier sine series. I believe I showed that for part 3 we have uniform convergence based on some estimates of the series but I would like to know the general result for these sorts of objects.

In general, if you have good references on calculus like Fourier Analysis for beginners please share them. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure with the expression of $a_n $

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima Well, I don't know much rigor behind the Fourier sine series. But if you just assume that $$\sin(nx)$$ are basis (after normalization) then $$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \left[ \int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin(nx) dx + \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)dx \right] = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \left[ \frac{-\cos(nx)}{n} \right]_0^\pi = \frac{2(1-(-1)^{n})}{\pi n}.$$

Comment: Dirichlet's test for series should work for pointwise convergence.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima I agree with this. Yet, do you know what is the pointwise limit?

Comment: I would use the $M$-test to see if there is uniform convergence.

Comment: You look for which $x $, the series $\sum a_n\sin (nx ) $ is convergent.

Comment: @Wolfy What is $M$-test?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima What do you mean?

Comment: @Vadim You can find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test There are examples as well. I think it is pretty easy to follow.

Comment: @wolfy I don't think it will work. I believe that the sum of absolute values of the above is divergent. Morally speaking, if you take $x$ small enough, then the sum of absolute values is more than summing half of the terms of Harmonic series times $\sin(\pi/4)$

Comment: If a series of continuous functions converges uniformly, then the limit is continuous.

Comment: point-wise continuity.  The Gibbs phenomenon says that the Fourier series at jump discontinuity will go through the midpoint of the jump.  The uniform limit theorem says that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous, but this function is discontinuous, so the uniform limit does not exist.